# Where to put templates in my MVC structure? And where to put defines?

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller, structure, templating

I have the following structure in my MVC:

```
1) app
    1. controllers
        Home.class.php
    2. core
        App.class.php
        Controller.class.php
    3. models
        User.class.php
    4. views
        - home
            index.php
        .htaccess
        init.php
2) public
    1. css
    2. js
    .htaccess
    index.php
```

Now I'd like to implement templating too. I've used the following code before to use templating in my projects.

```
<?php
    class Template
    {
        private $assignedValues = array();
        private $tpl;

        public function __construct($_path = '')
        {
            if(!empty($_path)){
                if(file_exists($_path)){
                    $this->tpl = file_get_contents($_path);
                }
                else{
                    echo '<b>Template Error:</b> File Inclusion Error.';
                }
            }
        }

        public function assign($_searchString, $_replaceString)
        {
            if(!empty($_searchString)){
                $this->assignedValues[strtoupper($_searchString)] = $_replaceString;
            }
        }

        public function show()
        {
            if(count($this->assignedValues > 0)){
                foreach ($this->assignedValues as $key => $value) {
                    $this->tpl = str_replace('{'.$key.'}', $value, $this->tpl);
                }
            }

            echo $this->tpl;

        }

    }
```

So where would I have to put this class? And where would be the folder with the templates in it? I've also used the default file with defines in it. What would be the beste place to drop my defines file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not in:

> app/views/layouts/your-template.php

It makes sense to me to keep it with the rest of your "view" based structure as it is a template.

This is also the way [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade) (a php framework) does it.

Comment: Thank you! And the class that handle's the template? (Given in the question)

Comment: That ones up for more of a debate.  If you are growing this to a large scale framework you might consider starting a /lib or /src folder somewhere (such as in /app/lib or /app/src).  I think for now, the Template.class.php could go into the /app/core folder. It seems this class is designed to be part of your "core" framework functionality.